# Why am I getting this message invalid syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, if-statement, syntax

i write code if statement but there is a wrong in it .
this is the code

```
mark = float(input('enter your mark : '))
if mark < 50:
    result = 'failed'
elif mark >= 50 and < 75:
    result = 'accepted'
elif mark >= 75 and < 85:
    result = 'good'
elif mark >= 85 and < 90:
    result = 'very good'
else:
    result = 'excellent'
print(result)
```

the message appear is invalid syntax in line 4 about < assignment 
any help here guys?

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: I **strongly recommend** reading this article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax is either `elif mark >= 50 and mark < 75:` or `elif 50 <= mark < 75:`

Comment: elif mark >= 50 and mark < 75 is the right syntax thanx sammy

Answer (score 3):

`mark >= 50 and < 75` is not a valid expression, you must write `mark >= 50 and mark < 75` instead. Alternatively, you can use a chained comparison: `50 <= mark < 75`.

Comment: elif mark >= 50 and mark < 75 is the right syntax thank you aran

Comment: @haithemhussien Glad I could help! Please remember to leave an upvote if you found my answer useful!

Comment: your is very good and i give upvote i'm a new contributor like you :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be your code that actually runs:

```
mark = float(input('enter your mark : '))
if mark < 50:
    result = 'failed'
elif mark >= 50 and mark < 75:
    result = 'accepted'
elif mark >= 75 and mark < 85:
    result = 'good'
elif mark >= 85 and mark < 90:
    result = 'very good'
else:
    result = 'excellent'
print(result)
```

As others stated `mark >= 50 and < 85` is not valid in Python.